# Can I exploit GPU to do AES encryption from .NET? If so, how?

Tags: .net, opengl, encryption, aes, gpu

Interesting paper from Trinity College of Dublin:
[AES Encryption Implementation and Analysis
on Commodity Graphics Processing Units](https://www.cs.tcd.ie/~harrisoo/publications/AES_On_GPU.pdf)

Their technique uses openGL to enlist the GPU to do the numeric transforms required by AES.

How difficult would it be to expose this capability - performing stream encryption - via a managed .NET library?

How would I get started?  Hints?  Examples?

**EDIT**: Anyone have experiences to relate using CUDA or Accelerator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Microsoft's [Accelerator](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/Accelerator/) library. It gives you access to the GPU through .NET.

After looking into the work required more, this is a pretty non-trivial thing to do (unless you like re-writing AES algorithms). It is possible however.

There may be other C# API's out there, but one I came across was [Bouncy Castle API](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/). What you would have to do is take Microsoft's Accelerator API and use it anywhere a math operation is performed within the source code of the AES algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest creating a managed wrapper around a CUDA/(c++/cli) implementation OR using cuda.net to do everything *but* the kernel itself in c#. 
There is really no way to do the actual kernel implementation in a high-level language, with CUDA you need to use c, with opengl/directx you need to use shaders.
To get started either take a look at cuda.net or download the CUDA SDK and examples to get an introduction to gpgpu programming.

Comment: There's already a CUDA.NET wrapper here: http://www.hoopoe-cloud.com/Solutions/CUDA.NET/Default.aspx

Comment: I did not say to use a wrapper around CUDA, but a wrapper around a CUDA _implementation_. The difference is crucial since if you use cuda.net you end up having to do a lot of stuff that is much easier in c/c++. I also had a lot of trouble with cuda.net, several of the samples do not even work. In addition you will have to do a lot of memory/buffer management in c#, something which is usually easier in c/c++.
You will also have to choose between managed memory (no pagelocked memory, thus much lower memory transfer performance) or unmanaged memory (much more overhead if you want to work in c#).

Answer (score 2):

Another option is [Brahma](http://brahma.ananthonline.net/) (the web site seems to be down atm).

Web site Quote:

> What is Brahma?
>
> Brahma is an open-source library written for the .NET 3.5 framework (in C# 3.0), to provide high-level access to parallel streaming computations on a variety of processors.
>   Please note at while at this time Brahma has a GPU provider (and its focus is GPGPU), it can be adapted to run on any kind of processor.
>
> What can I do with Brahma?
>
> Brahma 2.0 uses C# 3.0's new LINQ syntax to specify streaming transformation of data. Using Brahma, you can mix statements that run on the GPU and statements that run on the CPU inside a single method! With absolutely no glue code required, a complex multipass GPU computation with intervening CPU operations can be performed with just a few lines of code. All the glue and shader code required is automatically generated by Brahma. All you need to do is write high-level .NET code.

I haven't used it but I just recently listened to a [podcast](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=466) about it on .NET rocks.  It sounds like a good library to use if you don't want to get into learning the GPU shader language(s).

Here is the [sourceforge link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/brahma-fx/).

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you use to integrate C# to the GPU, you should use a CUDA implementation of AES.  They are the fastest out there.  The fastest implementation looks like it comes from the same guys you linked to - [Trinity group](https://www.cs.tcd.ie/~harrisoo/research.html).  Look at the Practical Symmetric Key Cryptography on Modern Graphics Hardware paper.